# How to change the descriptive text on the menus admin page?

Tags: admin, wp-admin

On the menus admin page, it says 'Drag each item into the order you prefer. Click the arrow on the right of the item to reveal additional configuration options.'

I would like to modify this to ' Drag each item into the order you prefer. The maximum top level pages is 6'.

How can I do this? Thanks. I have been trying to figure it out but have got no where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are referring to is located in here: `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`. But we will not edit directly. We will use `functions.php` for the convenience of preserving the changes after an upgrade.

Use the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {

 $words = array(
                    // 'word to translate' = > 'translation'
                    'Click the arrow on the right of the item to reveal additional configuration options.' => 'The maximum top level pages is 6',
                );

 $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
 return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you that worked. How did you know to use `gettext`,`ngettext` and `$words` ? I'm new to wordpress development and would really appreciate if you told me.

Comment: Mostly you can search in Codex. But this is an excellent website to get snippets. [WPSnipp](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/use-gettext-ngetext-to-replace-array-of-words-in-wpadmin/) Just needed to edit the string and tested in my dev server admin panel. Good Luck! :)